# Why does eclipse make delegated methods protected by default?

Tags: android, eclipse

In Eclipse, in Android project, if I type something like:

```
void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
            handleClick();
         });
}
```

Eclipse then suggests to add `handleClick()` implementation for me giving me two choices: either in `OnClickListener` or in the enclosing `Activity`.

So, if I tell Eclipse to implement `handleClick()` in the Activity it does so and it makes `handleClick()` a `protected` method.

I wonder why not `private`, what's the rationale behind that, why it gets `protected`?

Comment: That must be the reason as you and Chris Thompson below explained, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, and this is a guess, but a delegate method is a lot more powerful if it's protected.  Being protected allows subclasses to override it, providing an interface for future expansion etc via dynamic dispatch.  However, if it's private, then all you're accomplishing is moving some code around.  You might as well put the content of the method in the body of `onClick`

Comment: In fairness, "just moving code around" is called "refactoring", and is a valid reason to move code around.